# Internal Operations Occurring During Python for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know from some testing the below code snippet is working as intended, but I want to know what is occurring on the backend of python here

```
for c in curr.getChildren():
  if point in c:
    change = True
    curr = c
```

for a toy example:

```
x = [1,2,3]
for c in x:
  print ('hi')
  if c == 2:
    x = 2
```

The print statement fires three times and the x is reassigned to 2. Is python internally representing the container as a deep copy somewhere or is the iterator simply intrinsically linked to the memory location of this container. Is this safe? Generally curious what is happening here behind the scenes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python evaluates the element once (`x`) and gets an iterator that it loops through (`c`). This is why your loop is not iterating only once, as you'd desire.

Here are a couple locations explaining such behavior.

[docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement)

[github.com/python/cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Doc/reference/compound_stmts.rst#the-keywordfor-statement)

In regards to your concern of safety, it's safe in the sense that you won't mess up your `for` loop. The caveat being, if you are using a mutable object, the `for` loop could attempt to go past the index (or not reach the end) of the object, if you're removing data (or adding data).

Comment: Ok, this was mostly what I was expecting, for this application I can live with not breaking out of the loop, but I'm glad to know it's performing internally how I was thinking.